Issues with saving changes in QField - How to Resolve Pending Changes?
I'm experiencing issues in QField where my changes keep getting stuck as "pending" and I'm unable to successfully save or sync them. I've checked my internet connection and project settings, but the problem persists. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can resolve it?

Further details would help with troubleshooting - is the layer you're saving changes to online, or is it offline, what sort of layer is it (gpkg? Postgres?), is this a QFieldCloud project? A screenshot would also make it easier. I also recommend checking the QField github issues page or posting there. https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues
